# Properly define attributes in a code analyzer and expose to utilizing projects?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

**Summary**
I have a code analyzer I've written.  This analyzer is being used in another project.  I would like to define attributes in the analyzer that the utilizing project can use to direct the analyzer's behavior.

**Question**
What is the proper way to define attributes for a code analyzer, and expose them to utilizing projects?

**Current Approach**
My current approach defines a separate `Analyzer.interface` project that `Analyzer` depends on.  `Analyzer` targets .NET Core 2.0, while `Analyzer.interface` targets .NET Framework 4.0. `Analyzer.Interface` only declares the attribute classes that I need. The `UtilizingProject` targets .NET Framework 4.0 and uses this analyzer.

This *works*, however it has several issues.

First, when building the analyzer, it gives warnings:
"ProjectReference Analyzer.Interface was resolved using '.NETFramework,Version=4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'"
This doesn't appear to break anything, but indicates to me that I am likely approaching this incorrectly.

Second, when updating the utilizing project from .NET Framework 4.0 to .NET Framework 4.7.1, it now reports:
"Unable to find package Analyzer.Interface"

**Ideal Solution**
The ideal solution that I'm looking for would not cause any warnings, and would be flexible enough to be used in a wide array of projects, independent of version.  I see no reason that versioning should be critical for an analyzer, so this seems like it *should* be feasible, but if it's not I welcome an explanation as to why.  I am willing to consider alternate approaches if there is a more "standard" way of handling this situation (my searches have not yielded any relevant results).

Comment: Can I check: are the package-dependencies between the analyalzer project and something else? To be brutally honest, dependencies in analyzers/generators is a complete mess, and only kinda sorta works - you're usually better off avoiding the need. Why do you need Analyzer.Interface to exist? What does it provide? Is that something that your regular project also targets, so declare attributes? If so: if it was me, I'd simply recognize the attributes (in the analyzer) by fully qualified name, without using the reference. You can then even ship the analyzer *in the nuget package of the other one*

Comment: The attributes are used to "instruct" the analyzer on how to view/process certain methods/fields.  The utilizing project needs the attributes to properly annotate things, and the analyzer needs them to understand what the end project intends.

You are suggesting having the analyzer not depend on Analyzer.Interface, and to instead just use the name?  And then still shipping the .Interface so that utilizing projects can reference it?

Comment: "You are suggesting having the analyzer not depend on Analyzer.Interface, and to instead just use the name?" - yes, precisely that (I've written such; it works fine); "And then still shipping the .Interface so that utilizing projects can reference it" - yes, but more: you can embed the analyzer inside the package for .Interface, meaning that installing the .Interface package (to get the attributes) *automatically* adds the analyzer too

Comment: @MarcGravell: Can you clarify what exactly you mean by "embed the analyzer inside the package for .Interface"?  I assume the .Interface project would build the package, would embedding just be a matter of having the .Interface project reference the analyzer project?  Also, what is the advantage here of packing the .Interface rather than the analyzer?  Finally, do you have suggestions on what to have .Interface target?  I would have thought lower would be more compatible, but I don't seem to be able to use the net40 version in my net471 project.  Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: you need to configure it to push the output into a very specific folder structure; here's an example where DapperAOT refs the analyzer package - see the path data: https://github.com/DapperLib/DapperAOT/blob/main/src/Dapper.AOT/Dapper.AOT.csproj